# Show that $Z_n=\frac{X_n}{m^n}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

the book of Ross & Pekoz have the next statement:

> A branching process follows the size of a population
> over succeeding generations. It supposes that, independent of what
> occurred in prior generations, each individual in generation $n$ independently has $j$ offspring with probability $p_j$, $j \geq 0$.
>
> The offspring
> of individuals of generation $n$ then make up generation $n + 1$. Let
> $X_n$ denote the number of individuals in generation $n$.
>
> Assuming
> that m = $\sum_{j}jp_j$, the mean number of offspring of an individual,
> is finite it is east to verify that $Z_n = X_n/m^n, n ≥ 0$, is a martingale.

and I'm trying to verify that $Z_n$ is indeed a martingale, so I check that:

1. $Z_n$ is measurable respect $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$
2. $Z_n$ is adapted to $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$

But in the next part I don't see how to continue:

3. $E[Z_n+1|\sigma(X-1,...,X_n)]=Z_n$

Because I only come with $E[Z_{n+1}|\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)]=\frac{E[X_{n+1}|\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)]}{m^{n+1}}.$

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Every book on Branching Processess  has a proof of this basic thorem. See the book by Athreya and Ney, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since this is in discrete time, and $X$ and $Z$ generate the same $\sigma$-Algebra ($Z$ is just some constant times $X$) we only have to show that
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1}|X_{n}] = Z_{n}.$$

Now, given that we know that in generation $n$ we have $X_{n}$ members of the population, which each generate $j$ offspring with probability $p_j$ independently, the expected value for the $n+1$-th generation, divided by $m^{n+1}$ is

$$\mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1}|X_{n}] = \frac{1}{m^{n+1}} \sum_{i=1}^{X_{n}} \sum_j p_j = \frac{1}{m^{n+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{X_{n}} m = X_{n}\frac{m}{m^{n+1}} = \frac{X_{n}}{m^{n}} = Z_n$$